# Kafka minimal (production) setup

Tags: apache-kafka

We plan to use Apache Kafka in our product as it seems to handle well horizontal scaling and shock absorbing - and our cloud environment requires these features.

But we also plan to deploy our product to envrironments, where RAM consumption is a priority. These environments will however not require big throughput. Let's say 1MB/s, with bigger deployments 5MB/s. Messages will be rather small, 1kB each.

We do not require HA in for these deployments, nor any perfect performance. We just need it to be stable, 24h retention (we'll have enough space on reasonable disks).

Would it be possible to run Kafka under these conditions with 1GB RAM? (or even less). If not, what will be the minimal setup?

Comment: [This](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/kafka/latest/topics/kafka_performance.html#concept_exp_hzk_br) may be helpful when calculating the best configuration for your use case. One of the key points is:

*Brokers allocate a buffer the size of ``replica.fetch.max.bytes`` for each partition they replicate. If ``replica.fetch.max.bytes`` is set to 1 MiB, and you have 1000 partitions, about 1 GiB of RAM is required. Ensure that the number of partitions multiplied by the size of the largest message does not exceed available memory.*

Comment: With one Kafka, I will have just one broker. So number of partitions per topic will be 1. If we'll have let's say 100 topics, for maintaining the topics 100MB shall be required. Aand also I do not know, if this even applies - as with 1 node, replication does not make much sense. But I suppose that even if it does, with this limited setup, some required minimal overhead will kick in.

Comment: That makes sense. That being said, it appears 1GB of RAM will work for you.

Answer (score 13):

Just in case anyone is also interrested in this question. We've tested single node Kafka with Xmx=1GB, ingesting twitter stream API (~50 messages a second, each 5-10kB).

We also tried to stop kafka consumer for some time, so that there is a lot of messages, when it gets started again. And we've achived 2500 messages a second on this side of Kafka.

Machines used: 2x t2.medium from AWS - one for ingest and broker, one for consumer.

Comment: But what is the _minimum_ required?  You did not really answer your own question carefully - and I'm really quite interested in that result

Comment: Your answer would help a lot more if you included findings from your tests.

Comment: We have not tested on smaller machines, as this was practical minimum in our case. Going further down will hit the definition of "running"... as smaller memory means much smaller free chunk for mmaps.... so it will start, but will not be able to handle too many messages, or will have unstable performance. But we did not go this deep as this kind of test would be too time consuming for our cause. But if someone has the numbers, I am interested as well :-)